# Overwrite only specific fields of a csv file in matlab

Tags: matlab, csv, file-io

I'd like to write cell arrays of strings to csv files and overwrite parts of them with numerical data. I guess, for illustrative purposes we could use two matrices:

```
a = ones(5,5);
b = zeros(3,3);
```

I'd like to write a to a csv file and then overwrite specific fields of this file with b, resulting in:

```
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0
```

Is there a way to do this in matlab? I tried

```
csvwrite('foo.csv', a);
dlmwrite('foo.csv', b, 'roffset', 2, 'coffset', 2)
```

but this would overwrite the entire file. I would be thankful for any suggestions.

Comment: Can u make first e.g. a 'c' array with overwritten parts and then write it into the csv file?

Comment: You could use some combination of 'fread', 'fseek', 'frewind', and 'fwrite' to rewrite only the bytes of the file that should be changed.  I'm not sure of a way to do it easily.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution based on Marcin's suggestion:

```
datsize = size(a);
precision = 6;
output_cell = reshape(cellstr(num2str(a(:),precision)), size(a));

for i = 3:datsize(1,1),
 for j = 3:datsize(1,2),
    output_textdata(i,j) = output_cell(i-2,j-2);
 end
end

cell2csv('foo.csv', output_textdata);
```

While this produces the desired outcome three issues remain. First, the 'precision' varies from cell to cell. Second, which is not a problem for the intended limited application of this script, this code would produce an error if matrix b partially overlapped with matrix a and partially exceeded its dimensions, e.g., b had a size of 4x4 and were superimposed on a starting from a(3,3). Third, this workaround doesn't answer the more general question of whether only specific fields of a csv can be overwritten in matlab.